# OKTA Session Id Retrieval

Tags: okta, okta-api

I have SSO/SAML working using the OKTA Apis with my SP. My question is, is there a way to get the current OKTA session Id from within my application?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the session status client side using the https://org.okta.com/api/v1/sessions/me API. To note, the /sessions/me endpoint doesn't require an API key and is also [CORS enabled](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/enabling_cors.html).

The only other way to get the session id is to have created it [via the API](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/sessions.html#create-session-with-session-token) and saved it somewhere, usually in a cookie, so it can be retrieved later.